# Вывод пробелов

Tags: php

```
$opis=explode("<hr>",$rr['opis']);
            if($opis[1])
            echo '<table cellpadding="3" cellspacing="3" width=100%><td><div class="auto_prodam_idvobor">'.str_replace("\n","<br><br>",$opis[1]).'</div></td></tr></table><br>';
```

При выводе текста обрезает пробелы до 1-го.

Как вывести текст, чтобы все пробелы выводились, записанные в БД?

Comment: Неразрывные пробелы не воспринимает... Так и выводит их &nbsp;&nbsp;

Answer (score 2):

Тег <pre> , ну или менять их на неразрывные пробелы - &nbsp;

Comment: Да. Тег <pre> промог, спасибо!